# Can we have a vote-to-reopen tag here on meta ELU?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close, question-closure

We have a `vote-to-close` tag, but it would be nice to have a `vote-to-reopen` tag also, for those of us who believe our questions were wrongfully closed.

Comment: We use the question closure tag for this purpose.

Comment: I just found that one. :) I'll attempt to update the excerpt for it to make it more clear what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

@Kit Z. Fox has kindly pointed out that the [question-closure tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question-closure) is for this purpose.